# I'm looking for a good database regrouping all NetApp products and solution

Tags: netapp

> **First Question**: I would like to inform myself about [NetApp](http://www.netapp.com), and I'm looking for a good, complete database where all [products](http://www.netapp.com/us/products/) and [solultions](http://www.netapp.com/us/solutions/) are regrouped, with their features and technical informations. The website is full of informations, but I'd like something more compact, like a poster or similar.
>
> **Second question**: If anyone has some personnal experience or feedback about NetApp, it would be great to here what you think about it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You want a database of NetApp's products? Have you tried talking to NetApp?..

Comment: Hi Erik, no I haven't. But it might be a good idea indeed. I'll try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QN2: My experience with Netapp has been fantastic so far (Storage system), their auto support is just great.

Comment: Good to know! I'm about to go work for the NetApp Support, that's also the reason why I'm asking... to know a little bit what I'm engaging myself into... Thanks for the info.